# Broken mango seedling stem

Tags: plant-health, plant-recommendations, damage

[image]

I broke my mango seedling stem tip. Stem is still growing but it has no leaves at all. And to tell you the truth i don't understand from where could the leaves grow. Any  ideas on this matter would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

I have damaged mango seedlings before... What usually happens is the stem will keep growing for a while and might even have a little branch... but the main growth will likely come from another stem that will emerge from the middle of the seed somewhere, but if you started another one today it would win in a race to 24 inches (60cm).